# Some confusion on the method instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) of PagerAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-pageradapter

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView view = new ImageView();
      container.addView(view);
      return view;
}
```

I read some example code of PagerAdapter, and they all write the addview method. This above is some simple code, And I know 'return view' is used for return the view for display, But what is the 
    container.addView(view) 
do?

Answer (score 21):

Adding the view to the container is actually what makes it appear on-screen. The object returned by `instantiateItem` is just a key/identifier; it just so happens that using the actual view for this purpose tends to be convenient if you aren't using something like a `Fragment` to manage the view for the page. (See the source for `FragmentPagerAdapter` for an example.)

The PagerAdapter method `isViewFromObject` helps the pager know which view belongs to which key. If you're just returning the view as the key object, you can implement this method trivially as:

```
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

Comment: if "Adding the view to the container is actually what makes it appear on-screen. ", what is  the "return view" do? Thanks for answering.

Comment: It is the identity for ViewPager to use.

Comment: This answer and than @hackbod comment answered me to so many opened questioned about ViewPager! Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

**As per comments include in Source Code of PageAdapter**

```
public abstract Object instantiateItem(View container, int position);
```

Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
      for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
      must ensure this is done by the time it returns from

> **Container** The containing View in which the page will be shown.
>
> **Position**  The page position to be instantiated.
>
> **Returns** an Object representing the new page.This does not   need to
>   be a View, but can be some other container of the page.